# Stripe React Issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql, stripe-payments

I am new here first post! Woohoo my code has bugs! Jokes aside...

I am trying to get my success page on my mockup to add the credits to my user in my database.

My checkout works just fine, I encounter no errors but after successful test purchase I get a loading response which is an if block I set up if no userData is found.

Here is my Success.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@apollo/client' // Import useQuery
import { UPDATE_CREDITS } from '../utils/mutations'
import { GET_USER_BY_ID } from '../utils/queries' // Import your query
import {
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody,
    CardFooter,
    Divider,
    Button
} from '@nextui-org/react'

const priceIds = {
    5: 5,
    15: 15,
    25: 25
}

const SuccessPage = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const location = useLocation()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const userSelection = location.state?.userSelection
    const [updateCredits, { data, loading, error: mutationError }] =
        useMutation(UPDATE_CREDITS)

    const userId = 'userIdValue'

    const {
        loading: queryLoading,
        data: userDataQuery,
        error: queryError
    } = useQuery(GET_USER_BY_ID, {
        variables: { userId: userId },
        skip: !userSelection
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        
        console.log('User selection:', userSelection)

        if (userSelection) {
            updateCredits({ variables: { credits: priceIds[userSelection] } })
                .then((response) => {
                    setUserData(response.data.updateCredits)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setError(err.message)
                })
        }
    }, [userSelection, updateCredits])

    const handleReturnHome = () => {
        navigate('/') // Redirect to home page
    }

    if (error || queryError) {
        return <div>Error: {error || queryError.message}</div>
    }

    if (loading || queryLoading || !userData) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
        <div className='flex flex-row justify-center w-full mx-auto my-40'>
            <section className='flex w-full justify-center align-center'>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader className='flex-col gap-3'>
                        <div className='flex flex-col'>
                            <p className='text-md'>Congratulations</p>
                            <p className='text-small text-default-500'>
                                Your order has been placed successfully.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <Divider />
                    <CardBody>
                        <h1>Payment Successful!</h1>
                        <p>Your new credit balance: {userData?.credits}</p>
                        <Button
                            className='text-md'
                            color='primary'
                            radius='full'
                            size='sm'
                            onClick={handleReturnHome}>
                            Return to Home
                        </Button>
                    </CardBody>
                    <Divider />
                    <CardFooter>
                        <p className='text-small text-default-500'>
                            You will now be navigated to the Home page.
                        </p>
                    </CardFooter>
                </Card>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SuccessPage
```

Here is my Checkout.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function Checkout() {
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const createStripeSession = async (credits) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/create-stripe-session', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ credits })
            })

            const sessionData = await response.json()
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(sessionData.message || 'Error creating Stripe session')
            }

            navigate('/success', { state: { userSelection: credits } })

            window.location.href = sessionData.url
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message)
        }
    }

    const handleCheckout = (credits) => {
        console.log('Credits:', credits)

        createStripeSession(credits)
    }

    return (
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen mx-auto'>
            <div className='text-center mb-4'>
                <h2 className='text-xl font-semibold'>Buy Credits</h2>
                {error && <p className='text-red-500'>{error}</p>}
                <div className='my-2'>
                    <p className='text-lg'>Choose a credit option:</p>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => handleCheckout(5)}
                        className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-2'>
                        5 credits - $5
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => handleCheckout(15)}
                        className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-2'>
                        15 credits - $15
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => handleCheckout(25)}
                        className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-2'>
                        25 credits - $25
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout
```

Lastly heres a look at my queries, and mutations

```
export const GET_USER_BY_ID = gql`
    query GetUserById($userId: ID!) {
        user(id: $userId) {
            id
            credits
        }
    }
`
```

```
export const UPDATE_CREDITS = gql`
    mutation UpdateCredits($credits: Int!) {
        UpdateCredits(credits: $credits) {
            _id
            credits
        }
    }
`
```

I have attempted to log out the credits and user
the credits do log but the user shows undefined